# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene' to 'string' [Assembly-CSharp] Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
int Scenenumber=SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
public void NextLevel(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(Scenenumber+1));
    }
```

In unity 2d, I am trying to make a script to load next scene but it doesnt work and gives me and error what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call SceneManager again inside of LoadScene.

Just call like this:

```cs
int Scenenumber = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
SceneManager.LoadScene(Scenenumber + 1);
```

If it still failing, double check if your scene is available at Build Settings and the check on the left is enabled.

Comment: You're welcome! Just a tip... Be careful while using index to change scenes, because any changes on Build Settings may break it. One thing that you can do, is create a Static object that holds every scene name and which level is it and loading the scene based on the information. With this, you can make any changes at the Build Settings and won't break your project.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `name` to load:

```
int Scenenumber=SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
public void NextLevel(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(Scenenumber+1).name);
    }
```

or

```
string SceneName=SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;;
public void NextLevel(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneName);
    }
```